# position div using css

Tags: css, html

Could you please refer this http://jsfiddle.net/BRWWN/ 
How can I position the divs in the following order.

The blue div shows in left as a left side menu, the red div comes right of the blue div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `float:left;` to both:

```
#a {
 width: 25%;
 border: thick solid Blue;
 height: 200px;
 display:inline;
 float:left;
}

#b {
 width: 25%;
 border: thick solid Red;
 height: 200px;
 display:inline;
 float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or change `display: inline` to `display: inline-block` for both div's.